# Alternatives to Hyper-V virtualization on Windows 10 Home

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015, emulation, hyper-v, xamarin.winphone

I just found out that in order to run Windows Phone emulator I need Hyper-V which is not supported in Windows 10 Home edition. I was offered an upgrade to Pro edition with a funny prize. 139$ for upgrade when I can buy full standalone license for Windows 10 Pro for 125$.

[image: Actually not funny at all.]

---

So here I am searching for alternatives to emulating windows phones on Visual Studio 2015 for app development.

Any clues/solution would much be appreciated.

---

Finally I ended up upgrading to temporary Windows 10 Pro edition. I will be using this for next 30 days and later decide to pay or downgrade to Home edition. Hyper-V and all the Pro features work as expected.

This is the default key to Pro edition given by Microsoft employees: 
**VK7JG-NPHTM-C97JM-9MPGT-3V66T**

Comment: You can probably buy a real Windows phone for less ;). The obvious choices are VirtualBox and VMWare Workstation Player, but neither are really smoothly compatible with Windows Phone emulator images...

Comment: True about phone, but WinPhone probably is not gonna be my main target, need more efficient solution. Googled some about VirtulaBox compatibility with VS2015 and didn't come across any promising results.. Thanks anyway

Comment: Or if you are still a student, apply to DreamSpark and install the server build, https://www.dreamspark.com/

Comment: @LexLi What's the server build?

Comment: @ggach It's Windows Server. Can be mostly transformed into a desktop install, but there will be differences. For Hyper-V and such it works just as well indeed. That's a good suggestion.

Comment: You should activate your DreamSpark account and then install https://www.dreamspark.com/Product/Product.aspx?productid=77 Then you can follow guides such as http://www.win2012workstation.com/ to configure it as a workstation.

Comment: > rubenvb Oh, I thought some cloud platform emulating different devices.

@LexLi It's strange they offer Win Server 2012 and not Education edition for free to students. Thanks! That solution will be my last resort.

Comment: I had a similar situation and I just purchased an upgrade key at https://www.cjs-cdkeys.com for 10$ when the official upgrade was 99$ and it worked fine.